# Failed to compile node module when i try to export db from firebase

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, node-modules

i am trying to access my data base from google firestore which is as follows

```
 import firebase from "firebase";
 const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    ....
});

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

export default db;
```

when i try to export this `db` to my other functional components i keep getting this error

[please look at the image which i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Zlp.png)

---

./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/esm5/prebuilt-db9cc925-eb007c37.js
Attempted import error: 'FetchXmlHttpFactory' is not exported from '@firebase/webchannel-wrapper' (imported as 'v').

---

i tried to

1. re install the node modules
2. also tried updating and removing node still

but still i keep getting this error. please help me out with this, been stuck here for almost a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you have not imported  correctly

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "...",
        ....
    });
    
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
    
export default db;
```

Also make sure to install right package `npm i firebase`